# Insert std::map into std::vector directly

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, stdvector, stdmap

Sorry if the question is very trivial.

I have a vector of maps:

```
typedef map<char, int> edges;
typedef vector<edges> nodes;

nodes n;
```

Now let's say I want to push a toy edge. I tried different things and what I worked is

```
edges e;        //declare an edge
e['c'] = 1;     //initialize it
n.push_back(e);  //push it to the vector
```

How can I just push the pair of values of an edge ('c' and 2) without having to declare a variable and initialize it?

Something like:

```
n.push_back(edges('c',2));
```

but compiler gives an error

```
error: no matching function for call to ‘std::map<char, int>::map(char, int)’
```

Comment: Which C++ Standard? C++11?

Comment: Yup, but if the solution is different for other standards I'd appreciate for completness if you could also provide the differences, thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [emplace\_back not working with std::vector<std::map<int, int>>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33207232/emplace-back-not-working-with-stdvectorstdmapint-int)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can list initialization:

```
nodes vec {
    { {'a', 12}, {'b', 32} },
    { {'c', 77} },
};

vec.push_back(
        { {'d', 88}, {'e', 99} }
        );
```

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit? I don't want to initialize the vector with some edges, I just want inside a loop to be able to push an edge to the vector without having to declare an edge, just passing the two values.

Comment: @SembeiNorimaki `push_back` is the same

Comment: @SembeiNorimaki you cannot push an edge to the vector because you don't have a vector of edge. You can push a map with one edge.

Comment: @SembeiNorimaki `std::map` has a constructor with a parameter of type `std::initializer_list`. Since `std::vector::push_back` has a parameter of `std::map` type here, that constructor is used (that's the reason why `emplace_back` does not work).

Answer (score 3):

Use an extended initializer list, like this:

```
n.push_back({ {'c', 2} });
```

<kbd>[Live demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/DsKFHFG79REU04kU)</kbd>

Requires C++11, or later.

Answer (score 0):

In your solution, you add `map` to vector instead of pairs. A method should iterate over each element to place it in vector. Therefore you can access to element with `n[0]['c']` etc.

I thought, using `for_each` and a lambda expression with passing vector reference to create a one line solution to add pairs into vector.

```
#include <algorithm> 

typedef map<char, int> edges;
//change this to take pair
typedef vector<pair<char, int>> nodes;

nodes n;
edges e;        //declare an edge

//map elements are pairs
for_each(e.begin(), e.end(), [&n](pair<char, int> p) { n.push_back(p); });
```

I hope this explains a solution for you.